# Automator: "run shell script" action only receives 1st line of input

Tags: macos, shell, service, automator

I have a weird looking problem (a similar one was asked here, but I don't want to accept that Automator only pipes only 1 line into the shell script action!: [Mac Automator: shell script gets only one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712079/mac-automator-shell-script-gets-only-one-line))

Automator-Workflow, type "service", 3 blocks:

1. Service receives "Text"
2. "run shell script", "bash", input via "stdin", shell script: "cat"
3. copy to clipboard"

When I select a multiline text and run this service only the first line finishes in the clipboard.

I made three other tests:

1. skip the shell script action - directly move the selection into the clipboard >> works!
2. instead of taking the input from the text selection the shell script action gets the input via an "read from clipboard" action from the clipboard >> fails (first line only)
3. instead of the "bash" action I selected a "perl" action >> fails (first line only)

So it seems obvious that the run shell script action contains the problem.
But I have used the shell script action (with web-content) many times before with no problems.

Any ideas?
Maybe a problem with encoding and or line-endings?

Answer (score 1):

At least on my Mac, when

- start Automator
- Choose Type -> Service

[image]

save at some name (mine is TestService), then

- go to TextEdit
- enter some text
- select

[image]

- from the TextEdit's menu: TextEdit -> Services -> TestService

[image]

Got to the clipboard the next:

```
2 ééééééééééé
3 íííííííííí
4 αβγδεζη
5 ЧШЩЪЫЬЭ
6 aaaaaaaaaa
```

Try exactly the above... ;)

Comment: Thank you - this is so kind of you to document your steps with screenshots!! (I should have done that *blush*)... This is exactly my setup (in German OSX). But what I found out by your suggestion is: when I type 5 lines into Textedit all works as expected, when I use a text from my source, paste it into Textedit and then run the service it fails! So maybe there is something with the line endings or similar (invisible). Usually I use a "xxd" as the shell command but in this case it does not get to the intersting point. I keep you updated.... Thanks again!

Comment: Weird. I played around, made more tests and now it works quite normal. One thing I changed was to switch off one of my tools (PopClip; next would have been PasteMaster) - then it worked. I switched it back on and it still works!?!? Mystery! Thanks!!!

Comment: Great! Good luck ;) (and consider click accpet if the answer works for you)

Comment: With a machine doing what it wants I really need "luck" (more than knowledge maybe) ;)

Comment: More testing: I used BBEdit for pasting the result to see it and it seems that BBedit is behaving different. I can copy/paste my original source (from MailMate) into BBedit which works. But the clipboard created by our simple service can not be pasted into BBedit fully (the clipboard has verything and can be pasted fully into Textedit or displayed with pbpaste in the Terminal). The file type in BBedit is standard: none, LF as linebreak and UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: So, seems, it is something with BBedit - and the automator works as needed. :) I'm using MacVim - so can't tell you anything about the BBedit.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. Instead of using the 'copy to clipboard' command I then tried executing another shell script (setting its input to 'stdin') containing only the command 'pbcopy'.
Afterwards line breaks were preserved properly.